# iPhone page curl example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

Is there a good example that shows how I can achieve a stopped page curl like in the Maps app? I want to be able to click a button that curls the page, and behind it is another view where I can click stuff etc. Are there any good examples that demonstrate this?

Comment: http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/

Comment: You want to stop the page curl midscreen, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)btnCurl_Clicked :(id)Sender
{


    ObjectMapController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    [ObjectLocation presentModalViewController:ObjectMapController animated:YES];



    [ObjectMapController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

in this example ObjectMapController is a object of mapcontroller class and Object location is also object of Location class.. mapcontroller contain only Blank class with xib and Location class only contain MapView also you need to third class for btnCurl_Clicked in this class just drag drop one button and connect it with Interface Builder and also create object of above both of class so it's work properly...

Answer (score 0):

There is an UIModalTransitionStyle for that :  UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl

Answer (score 0):

While the other solutions proffering `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` do work, they don't mimic Apple's Maps app because the simplest implementation only allows full-screen curls. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11406056/1148702) is a solution that allows a static toolbar during the curl animation.